# This has never come up before on SO?? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER

Tags: android, logcat, lg

I Googled `E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER` and I searched for it here and got no hits. I even Googled `stackoverflow E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER`. No USEFUL hits. (Google found 5000+ hits; first page had absolutely no help.)

That's pretty weird, from my experience.

```
? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1689600
? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1824000
? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1689600
? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1824000
```

It's a Logcat message (AS 2.3.3) that I get for my Android phone, an LG V10 (a.k.a., VS990) running Android 6.0. Closer inspection shows that maybe the two unique lines above repeat in pairs for a long time--maybe hundreds of lines with one or two of my `Log` outputs interspersed.

**I don't know what to do about it or if I should concern myself,** but it's a pain trying to read debug output.

---

FYI.

I get a lot of other messages that I don't know how to interpret, but most are `W`arnings.

But one message is an error that I am almost positive is for LG to fix some bug with the Clip Tray that contains the last 10 or so clipboard contents:

```
E/Editor: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
```

I can't hide the ClipTray and can only access last entry programmatically, not that it matters. I'm just suggesting that maybe LG has more than a couple of bugs. I didn't want an LG phone. Great duress forced the purchase.

Comment: You realize that logcat is a shared resource-  the messages in there don't necessarily come from your app.  If you see something like ThermalEngine and you don't have a class named that, the odds are you have some other app spamming the logs.

Comment: ANd with a bit of googling-  ThermalEngine is temperature monitoring software from QualComm used to make sure the CPU doesn't overheat.  It has nothing to do with your app, and there's nothing you can do to stop it.

Comment: @GabeSechan, yes I know Logcat is shared, as I said about LG's likely bug with `ClipTray`, but thanks for the Googling. I Googled the exact message, probably a mistake with no helpful hits. Usually this gives decent results. I Googled different strings that included "thermal engine" and found that, apparently LG "throttles" its V3 device once temp reaches 60 degrees (C). If you don't mind telling me... What did you Google? I need to sharpen my Googling skills (obviously).